# Laravel v5.2 + Nginx v1.2.1 Error 500 on Debian 7

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, debian

Here is my example `nginx` file, which I can get to work fine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;

    root /var/www/test/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name [the-ip-address];

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If I put an `index.php` file in `/var/www/test/public/index.php` it displays on the page fine.  But if I delete the folder `/var/www/test` and do a fresh install of Laravel as `/var/www/test` which includes a `public/index.php` all I get is error 500.

This should work, and I believe it has something to do with Debian and permissions.  I've tried running `sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/test` and `chmod -R o+w /var/www/test/storage` which did help before, but I must be missing something this time.

Any idea why my setup works, but not with Laravel?

Comment: Any information on nginx error.log or laravel laravel.log?

Comment: Try to run sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/test and sudo chmod -R 775  /var/www/test/storage. Don't allow storage to be writable by everyone.

Comment: And I think you should include fastcgi_params before you can use it? Try switching the last two lines in last location context. Then restart nginx to see whether it works.

Comment: @Carter First comment gave me some clues!  Seeing the logs made me realize that Laravel `.gitignore` file has `/vendor` in by default and thus I need to run `composer install` to get things up and running (I had pulled my Laravel app from a repository).  This allowed me to reach a "Whoops, something went wrong" screen, which was now the permissions issue.  The command that fixed it was `sudo chmod -R ug+rw storage` which apparently does not grant 777 permissions and is safe?  Do you know if this is true?  Either way, very helpful thanks!

Comment: Glad to know that. And sudo chmod -R ug+rw storage and sudo chmod -R 775 storage is doing the same thing. so it should be safe.